# Can we make the Hat Dash game able to jump with a mouse?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

I was just thinking that wouldn't it be nice if we were able to jump with using a mouse on Hat Dash?

Like now we only can press space, or press the up arrow to jump.

But wouldn't it be nice that if you can click with your mouse to jump?

Otherwise sometimes if you are looking at the screen during the Hat Dash game, and maybe you click the down arrow to make your unicorn smaller, if you want to get back to the up arrow you might click on the wrong arrow, whereas using the mouse maybe you will put one finger for the left click, and one finger for the scroll button, it would be nice if you jump with left click, kneel with the scroll button.

I am not sure if you would like to have a way to jump with the mouse too.

Anyway, I think it would be nice though.

Comment: Surely someone can write a userscript for that... ;)

Comment: @ShadowtheHatterWizard Lol I don't know how :-)

Comment: @Ollie 2760 seconds later...

Comment: @Ollie all good, monkey will wait!

Comment: I am grateful for this Question and these Notes. I didn't know I could use the up arrow to play *D'Oh! on me*   ...so, thx!

Comment: This is what I came up with: `document.querySelector('canvas').addEventListener('click', () => { Runner.instance_.playSound(Runner.instance_.soundFx.BUTTON_PRESS);  Runner.instance_.tRex.startJump(Runner.instance_.currentSpeed); })` (copy-paste in console). It doesn't jump immediately when you click in the canvas, but I'm not sure why.